# Ruby : Mechanize cannot find any content from the site what i want to check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

i want use auto login for specific web site

so i decided to use "Mechanize"

In example, like google.com, It works!

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

a = Mechanize.new { |agent|
    agent.user_agent_alias ="Windows Chrome"
}

page = a.get('http://www.google.com/')

puts page.search("div")
```

but when set url to http://lms.kyonggi.ac.kr/

I cannot find any content

I tried several functions like

- `page.links`
- `page.search(:id=>"wrap_login")`
- `page.search(".loginfrom")`....

But I cannot catch any content in this site

How can I get login contents from the site http://lms.kyonggi.ac.kr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That page has two `iframes` so you need to click the iframe first, then only you can find the elements.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

a = Mechanize.new
page = a.get('http://lms.kyonggi.ac.kr/')
p = page.frames[1].click
puts p.search("div")
```

Comment: Oh!! Thanks a lot! It works! :)
is there any docs about that rule?

Comment: @Dongkun Lee 
Refer this docs. I think this will help you
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize

Comment: Despite of your helpful comments, I think it's not working.
login form of the site above, it's ridiculous.
submit code like this


<span class="mm"><a href="javascript:login.loginCheck()"><img src="../images/n_btn_login.png" alt="로그인버튼"></a></span>


that korean means  "login button"
i heard mechanize is impossible to input value by js function
is there any other way to auto login

Comment: you can't, mechanize doesn't run javascript. use selenium or phantom

Comment: I think this will help you.
https://gist.github.com/huangzhichong/3284966